# How to use phpmailer to send email to multiple addresses one by one?

Tags: php, email, loops, foreach, phpmailer

I want a `foreach` loop to send email to multiple addresses each time I run the PHP code:

```
$id = "a@a.com
    b@c.com
    d@e.com";

$new = explode("\n", $id);

foreach ($new as $addr) {
    $mail->addAddress($addr);
}

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

But it put all the email addresses in `to` field and then sends the email.

So when someone get the email, he can see all the email addressees in the `to` field.

I want a code to send emails one by one.

Comment: Pretty much all the answers posted have problems. I suggest you use [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) that does exactly what you need.

Comment: Its not what I wanted. I already read that.

Comment: So why, having read that, did you choose to implement it entirely incorrectly, ignoring all of its correct advice?

Comment: because it puts all the email addresses in to field. I should use for or foreach and put all the things in the loop. this is the only way its working.

Comment: No it does not. Read the code. It puts a single address in the to field, sends the message, then clears the to address, then repeats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're actually adding multiple recipient *`addAddress()`* before actually sending the email.

So, ***after*** your loop...

```
$mail->addAddress('a@a.com');    // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('b@c.com');    // Add a another recipient
$mail->addAddress('d@e.com');    // Add a another recipient
```

the `TO` address is now `a@a.com, b@c.com, d@e.com`
And then... you're sending the email to all of them.

To send the email `one by one` I would initialize the `mail` object completely inside the loop.
(or call another function passing the address as an argument).

Answer (score 4):

Use method clearAddresses() (https://goo.gl/r5TR2B) in each loop to clear list of recipients:

```
$id = "a@a.com
    b@c.com
    d@e.com";

$new = explode("\n", $id);

foreach ($new as $addr) 
{
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->addAddress($addr);

    if (!$mail->send()) 
    {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
}
```

So You'll have the same object with the same body, subject and other settings.

Answer (score 2):

Use for example PHPMailer instead. You can use CC (EDIT: BCC) field with that. Nobody will see the other recipients then.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->AddBCC('a@a.com');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but this is not what I want. I know what is CC andI don't want do that

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through creating and sending mails - so create a new mail message for each receiver. That way they wouldn't be able to see the receiver. Example:

```
<?php
$people = array("person1@mail.com", "person2@mail.com", "person3@mail.com");

foreach($people as $p) {
    $message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";
    mail($p, 'My Subject', $message);
};

?>
```

Also you can use BCC field (this is hidden carbon copy).

PHPMailer as suggested before is nice, but you should note, that CC (plain carbon copy) will still be visible to other people in the mailing list.

Comment: how should I do that ? I don't want to use BCC and CC.

Comment: added example to the answer

Comment: Its not working. its a  PHPmailer and it don't has mail function. I want to use PHPmailer to send emails not just simple PHP mail() function

Comment: I read that. and I have more processional examples but could you please mention which example explained how to do what I want ?

Comment: Don't use that old example. Use the one I linked to in my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Initiate new PHPMailer inside foreach and send the email after that.

```
$id = "a@a.com
b@c.com
d@e.com";

$new = explode("\n", $id);

foreach ($new as $addr) {
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->addAddress($addr);

   if (!$mail->send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
   }
}
```